# Customize ng-repeat in AngularJS for every nth element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am trying to customize an `ng-repeat` to add something like a `br` tag to every 4th element. I have tried searching around but cannot seem to find a solid answer. Is there a simple way to add conditions to Angular for something like this? my `ng-repeat` is just adding some `spans` with content in them, but I need to start a new line every 4th element.

i.e. I want the following

`item1 item2 item3 item4
 item5 item6 item7 item8`

but right now it just does this

`item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8`

If there are any good articles relating to `ng-repeat` customization (for newbies) I would be thankful for links as well as everything I have found thus far is too difficult to understand.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="section">
    <div ng-repeat="items in MyList">
      <img ng-click="AddPoint($index)" src={{items.image}} />
      <span>{{items.currentPoint}}/{{items.endPoint}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could just use `$index` and apply it with `ng-if` on `<br ng-if="!($index%4)" />`

```
<div class="section">
    <div ng-repeat="items in MyList">
      <img ng-click="AddPoint($index)" src={{items.image}} />
      <span>{{items.currentPoint}}/{{items.endPoint}}</span>
      <br ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 4)" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update**

Based on the comment, you just need css for this just clear the float every [nth element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

```
.section > div:nth-of-type(4n+1){
  clear:both;
}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6OzdrzjZhpBFYlbetoSY?p=preview)**

If you are worried about support for older browsers then just add a class on specific condition:-

```
 <div ng-repeat="items in offensiveMasteries" ng-class="{wrap:!($index % 4)}">
```

and a rule for `.section > div.wrap`

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXRR5U2fxYm0tZhHDU1Y?p=preview)**

Comment: I swear AngularJS was built with black magic... lol thank you!

Comment: @Austin :) just updated some typo. Forgot that `$index` is zero based

Comment: I actually think I might need some CSS help too haha. The `br` is only pushing some items around. You mind looking at this **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGou6Mv7HZfusiTUvq8g?p=preview)**? I am working on the red section and making rows of 4.

Comment: @Austin You want to push every nth item down..You dont need to do this.. Css chould suffice

Comment: With the way my CSS is though, the `br` doesn't seem to be moving stuff down.

Comment: @Austin just add `.section > div:nth-of-type(4n+1){
  clear:both;
}`  http://plnkr.co/edit/wUYKqqP6HtLSnPztHrEL?p=preview

Comment: wow..CSS keeps surprising me too.. is `nth-of-type` typical CSS or like a bootstrap thing?

Comment: @Austin Yes updated, but you need to worry about support for older browsers

Comment: ah okay! If I wanted to make a condition for like the 18th item and I wanted to add a blank `div` or something, would I just make a CSS for it? I am following this layout and some items will be "blank" as nothing exist there as shown in this [layout](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Offense_Mastery_Tree_(Season_Four))

Comment: @Austin It depends you cannot add any element with css, but mostly you can adjust stuffs with css. It is powerful.. You can have pseudoelements etc.. instead of adding a new element. But again it depends...

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for all the help!! I just used `.section > div:nth-child(19){ visibility:hidden; }`

Comment: I know this thing is old -- but I've been messing with a layout issue for the past few hours. I knew the issue and I knew the fix but because it was all wrapped up in ng-repeat I kept failing at proper implementation. 

Found your answer and within seconds I'm rolling. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've solved your issue by now. But in the future, why not separate your list in javascript rather than on the front end. Just do some pre-rendering processing to get an object like this:

```js
// convert this
var list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6"];

// into this

var list = [
  ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
  ["item 4", "item 5", "item 6"]
];

// you could use a function like this
function convertToRowsOf3(list) {
  var newList = [];
  var row;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0){ // every 3rd one we're going to start a new row
      if(row instanceof Array)
        newList.push(row); // if the row exists add it to the newList
      
      row = [] // initalize new row
    }
    
    row.push(list[i]); // add each item to the row
  }
  
  if(row.length > 0) {
    newList.push(row);
  }
  
  return newList;
}
```

```html
<span ng-repeat="row in list">
  <span ng-repeat="col in row" ng-bind="col"></span><br>
</span>
```

Comment: This might be a little bit older response, but I'm thinking mobile compatibility might be an issue here, especially if you need to do some CSS resizing for two-column layouts on smaller devices.

Answer (score 2):

PSL's solution is for shure the neater one, but..
I got the same problem and in the end solved it in the following way (for those not wanting to tweak CSS or are not so into it)

```html
<div class="row responsive-sm" ng-repeat="exercise in exercises" ng-if="$even">
  <div class="col col-50">
    <div class="item item-stacked-label">
      {{exercise.title}}
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="col col-50" ng-if="!$last" ng-init="exercise = exercises[$index+1]">
    <div class="item item-stacked-label">
      {{exercise.title}}
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I had to put 2 exercises each row and just used ng-init to set again the actual picked one (exercise) to the next ($index+1) on each copy. Mind the !$last in the ng-if, without the output may corrupt the page as there are no more elements in the array to display

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved inserting a row every 6 items:

```
<div ng-class='row' ng-if="$index % 6 ? 'row' : ''" ng-repeat="genreNav in genres track by $index">

      <img src="{{genreNav.image}}" class="thumbnail img-responsive">

</div>
```