# AngularJS - ng-repeat horizontally x number of times, then new line

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to perform a simple `ng-repeat` on an `<li>`. In the past, i have created vertical `ng-repeat`. I am now trying to create a horizontal one, however, one that displays 4 items, then starts the `ng-repeat` again on a new line.

The way i have gone about this is using the grid-wrap technique (CSS) found here: http://builtbyboon.com/blog/proportional-grids

So each `<li>`, has a CSS class/width of one-quarter (25%).

Is this the correct/Angular way of going about it?  Or should i be using some kind of `$index` on the `<li>` and triggering a `<br>` when `$index == 3`  ?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul class="grid-wrap one-whole">
        <li ng-repeat="product in Products" class="grid-col one-quarter">
            <div class="product-container">
                <div>{{ product.ModelNo }}</div>
                <img ng-src="{{product.ImgURL}}" width="80%"/>
                <div>${{ product.Price }}</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-wrap {
  margin-left: -3em;
  /* the same as your gutter */
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-col {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3em;
  /* this is your gutter between columns */
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one-quarter {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Here's my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/REixcir0gL0HGCTvclYN?p=preview

Any other improvements you see feel free to add.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I did some research and found this answer:
[Customize ng-repeat in AngularJS for every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249388/customize-ng-repeat-in-angularjs-for-every-nth-element)

```
<div class="section">
<div ng-repeat="items in MyList">
  <img ng-click="AddPoint($index)" src={{items.image}} />
  <span>{{items.currentPoint}}/{{items.endPoint}}</span>
  <br ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 4)" />
</div>
```

So you could use this:

```
<br ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 4)" />
```

There doesn't seem to be a better way. You probably can't get around using index.