# CSS Columns not Working as Expected on Screen Resize

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div that displays some icons with text next to them.  The problem that I am having is that when the window is sized down, the images and text become a jumbled mess.  Here is what it looks like in full screen:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when the window is resized just a tad bit smaller:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
  .grid-wrap {
  margin-left: -3em;
  /* the same as your gutter */
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.grid-col {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 /* this is your gutter between columns */
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.newspaper-col{
     -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 20px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid; /* Firefox */
    column-rule-style: solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Firefox */
    column-rule-width: 1px;
}
.one-quarter {
  width: 25%;
}
.one-half{
    width:50%;
}

.one-third{
    width: 33%;
}
.one-whole{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
                                        <div style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px">
                                        <ul class="grid-wrap one-whole plain">
                                            <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="grid-col one-quarter">
                                                <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moduleOverride" ng-value="item" ng-click="moduleOverride(item)" ng-cloak>
                                                    <p><img style="float:left; margin-right:5px" ng-src="~/{{item.ModuleStateGraphicPath}}" /><span style="font-weight:bolder" ng-bind="item.ModuleHeaderText"></span><br /><span ng-bind="item.ModuleCalculatedStateText"></span></p>
                                                </span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
```

I tried to use the code found here [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249388/customize-ng-repeat-in-angularjs-for-every-nth-element) and I get the following:

[image]
 The CSS for that is:

```
.dashboard-section > span:nth-of-type(4n+1){
clear:both;
```

}

and the HTML is:

```
<div style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px" class="dashboard-section">
                                            <span ng-repeat="item in items">
                                                <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moduleOverride" ng-value="item" ng-click="moduleOverride(item)" ng-cloak>
                                                    <span><img style="float:left; margin-right:5px" ng-src="~/{{item.ModuleStateGraphicPath}}" /><span style="font-weight:bolder" ng-bind="item.ModuleHeaderText"></span><br /><span ng-bind="item.ModuleCalculatedStateText"></span></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <br ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 4)">
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
```

I was able to space out the above code by adding a width to the parent span as below, but it does not solve the resize problem:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; width:20%; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moduleOverride" ng-value="item" ng-click="moduleOverride(item)" ng-cloak>
                                                    <span><img style="float:left; margin-right:5px" ng-src="~/{{item.ModuleStateGraphicPath}}" /><span style="font-weight:bolder" ng-bind="item.ModuleHeaderText"></span><br /><span ng-bind="item.ModuleCalculatedStateText"></span></span>
                                                </span>
```

I'm at my wit's end here.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that the text next to the images wrapped differently on each image/text pair.  Some wrapped to 2, 3 and even 4 lines.  This prevented the following rows from wrapping all the way over to the left of the div (see photo below).

[image: Explanation]

By setting each span to the same height, each subsequent line was able to begin all the way to the left as needed.

```
                                                                <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px; height:100px; vertical-align:top; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moduleOverride" ng-value="item" ng-click="moduleOverride(item)" ng-cloak>
                                                                <span><img style="float:left; margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:25px" ng-src="~/{{item.ModuleStateGraphicPath}}" /><span style="font-weight:bolder; vertical-align:middle" ng-bind="item.ModuleHeaderText"></span><br /><p ng-bind="item.ModuleCalculatedStateText"><br /></p></span>
                                                            </span>
```

Hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

pretty easy using bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use ng-repeat as the items are being populated from the database.  How would this work with your answer?