# Change the background color of nth child in every parent DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have HTML as shown below. Using CSS, I want to change the background-color of `nth child div` of every `div`. If I click on the first *More Info* button I want to change the color of first child div of every div and so on.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
HTML : 

<div class="row" id="empListTable">   

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Hired
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Screened
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 15px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Pre-Qualified
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Approved
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       10
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       10
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                        6
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       2
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888;">
                                        Total Number of <br /> Employees hired
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                        Employees screened <br /> via phone or web
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                       Via Screened <br />employees
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                        Employees have <br />recieved tax credits
                                    </div>
                                </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:8px">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: You mean upon click the more info you want the background of the corresponding number to be highlighted?

Comment: There are many `divs` in your code example, and I'm guessing there are tons more throughout the rest of your site. You will have to be more specific about which elements you are trying to change the `background-color` of.

Comment: @Ralf17 thats right.

Comment: @KyleO I would like to target only the divs under div with id="empListTable"

Comment: so do you just want the columns, or the form groups?

Comment: @DannyBuonocore want the columns.

Comment: @rmkr if you want to highlight the entire columns, I'm going to have to change the mark up a bit, because right now it's a bit awkward. But my solution puts you on the right path.

Comment: @rmkr You can add an `ng-style` and use the `ng-click` that you already have in your code. I assume you have angularjs as a script. I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

So first, you get the index of the clicked button using the index method, then you can use the nth-child selector to change the background color.

**View the solution in full screen mode to see what is happening**

```js
var index = 1;
$(".button-container button").on('click', function(){
  // this will tell you which index you clicked
  $('.to-change div:nth-child('+index+')').css('background-color', 'white');
  index = $(this).index('button') + 1;
  $('.to-change div:nth-child('+index+')').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row" id="empListTable">   

                                <div class="form-group to-change col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Hired
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Screened
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 15px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Pre-Qualified
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                        Approved
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       10
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       10
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                        6
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold">
                                       2
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888;">
                                        Total Number of <br /> Employees hired
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                        Employees screened <br /> via phone or web
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                       Via Screened <br />employees
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                        Employees have <br />recieved tax credits
                                    </div>
                                </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 button-container" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:8px">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using AngularJS, you can add `ng-style` and modify your `ng-click` to change the `div` that you want to change. To change the background of the numbers in the corresponding column of your bootstrap row when you click the more info button:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="empListTable" ng-app="">   

                            <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-weight:bold">
                                    Hired
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                    Screened
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 15px;font-weight:bold">
                                    Pre-Qualified
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-weight:bold">
                                    Approved
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold" ng-style="col0">
                                   10
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 25px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold" ng-style="col1">
                                   10
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold" ng-style="col2">
                                    6
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 35px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold" ng-style="col3">
                                   2
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888;">
                                    Total Number of <br /> Employees hired
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                    Employees screened <br /> via phone or web
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                   Via Screened <br />employees
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:12px;color:#888">
                                    Employees have <br />recieved tax credits
                                </div>
                            </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-3" style="font-size:8px">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="col0={'background-color':'red'}">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="col1={'background-color':'blue'}">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="col2={'background-color':'green'}">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" ng-click="col3={'background-color':'yellow'}">More Info <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Go to [**angular ng-style**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for more examples.

Comment: thank u. How can I implement something like div:nth-of-type(val) {
    background-color: red;
}  using ng-style and ng-click

Comment: @rmkr Then, you might want also to familiarize yourself with `ng-repeat`. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249388/customize-ng-repeat-in-angularjs-for-every-nth-element.

Comment: @rmkr You can also read this: http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS3` `nth-child()` selector.

```
.parent > div:nth-child(1)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

For more reference, go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

```css
div
{
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(1)
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the `nth` child *and* ensure that its only `divs` you use this selector:

```
div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
}

div > div {
  background-color: blue;
}

div > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```