# Loop through items while inserting something else in the middle

Tags: angularjs

I need to loop through all items of an array, like `ng-repeat`, but to insert something else in the middle, say between 3rd and 4th.  How to do so?

```
WANT THIS
<img 1 />   <!-- this is one array item -->
<img 2 />
<img 3 />
<div>something else</div>   <!-- between array items -->
<img 4 />
<img 5 />
...
<img 9 />
```

There must be no extra elements wrapping several items above, because each item is a Bootstrap grid item which may flow to next row on narrower screens.  Below is not ok:

```
NOT OK
<div>
  <img 1 />
  <img 2 />
  <img 3 />
</div>
<div>something else</div>
<div>
  <img 4 />
  <img 5 />
  ...
  <img 9 />
</div>
```

---

**About duplicating**, I don't think this question duplicates the other question [Customize ng-repeat in AngularJS for every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249388/customize-ng-repeat-in-angularjs-for-every-nth-element).  The answer to the latter is

```
<div ng-repeat="items in MyList">
  <img />
  <br ng-if="...$index..." />
</div>
```

which outputs as

```
<div><img /></div>   <!-- one repeating item -->
<div><img /></div>
<div><img /></div>
<div><img /><br/></div>
```

but I need an extra tag **between** repeating items.

Comment: what does your array look like. do you want to add between array or between element

Comment: @AnilShrestha   The array is like `[{src:''},{src:''}]`.   Want to add between 3rd and 4th elements.

Comment: Is this AngularJS (v1) or Angular (v2+)?

Comment: @DeborahK  v1.5.8

Comment: Thanks. I just edited your tag to assign to AngularJS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let this is your array

```
array = []; //your array
```

now add some value to the required index of array. let you want to add in 4th place

```
array.splice(4, 0, "something else");




<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in array">

    <img ng-if="key != 4" />  
    <div ng-if="key == 4">something else</div>

</div>
```

hope it gives you some idea

Comment: Oh I did not expect modifying data for display.  But this should work.